# Very simple tcolorbox with picture in header

Tags: tcolorbox

I try to add `picture.png` in header of `tcolorbox`. I want to place this picture in bottom title belt.

This is my box:

```
\newtcolorbox{SimpleBox}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=red!0!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  title={\large Simple box},
}
```

How I can add `picture.png`?

When I add before `}` line

`\hfill\smash{\raisebox{-11pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{picture.png}}}`

I achieve errors...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add it inside the `title` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe} % just for the example

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{SimpleBox}{%
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=red!0!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  title={\large Simple box\hfill%
    \smash{\raisebox{-11pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image}}}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{SimpleBox}
Some Text
\end{SimpleBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Substitute `example-image` with your `picture.png`

Comment: I think `mwe` package is perfect for such dummy image use.

Comment: @HarishKumar I know. Just in case the image is not in the OP's TeX path.

Comment: @karlkoeller, thank you. And how I can place `picture.png` on left side of title?

Comment: @ama invert the two things inside the `title`